# Collapsed menu in Navbar: removing transparent margin from list elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching for a few hours on this and poured over the bootstrap code to no avail so here I am! I set my navbar to collapse at 991px and, once viewed, the list elements have the background color I wanted, but when you hover over them there's apparently a transparent margin for each list element. How would I get rid of this margin, i've been messing with  **navbar-nav li a** and my links in the navbar are H5s so also **navbar-nav li a H5**. The last list element is a dropdown link and in the media query when clicked it remains as if hovered over so I'm assuming there's a focus tag with it I just can't think exactly how to fix these two things (still very new to CSS/Bootstrap if you didn't know). Here is the HTML below and any help is very much appreciated!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#topFixedNavbar1"  aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a></div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">



    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right links">
      <li><a href="#"><h5>How We Work</h5></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><h5>Abous Us</h5></a></li>

      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><h5>Course Subjects</h5><span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

And here is the CSS (I included the whole file, but I'm pretty sure the problem will have to do with the media query):

```
body{
padding-top: 120px; 
background-color:#34A0CD;
}
.navbar-default{
height:120px;
}
.navbar-header, .navbar-brand{
height:120px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;   
}

#topFixedNavbar1{
height:120px;
}
.links{
height:120px;

}
.navbar-nav li a h5{
line-height:80px;
}
.dropdown li a {
line-height:30px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
.dropdown li a{
    line-height:30px;
}

.collapse.navbar-collapse{
    width:100%;

}
.links li a{

    width:100%;
}
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);

}

.navbar-collapse.in {
overflow-y: visible;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;

}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;

}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav li a h5{
line-height: 30px;
background-color: gray;
color: #F1E9E9;     
}
.navbar-nav li a{
    background-color:gray;
    width:100%;
}

.navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/* since 3.1.0 */
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
    display: block!important;
}
.collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
}

}
```

Comment: Forgot to include a snippet here's a link to when the collapsed button is clicked, and a list item is hovered over. http://imgur.com/6Y9jWKA

Comment: any online version? because the code snippet is not enough to reproduce the problem

Comment: No, just on my localhost :(, So I guess more specifically, from the picture, is there a transparent margin for list items when hovered over in the collapsed menu of bootstrap that needs to be changed? I was looking through it but just couldn't really get the right part (that I know of) even when searching for hover keyword.

Comment: I should see this so-called margin. Please edit your question and provide more relative `CSS` and `HTML`

Comment: My css file is already included fully, and the only HTML left off is the meta tags and css and js file inclusions. I haven't put any code in the css for this  margin in question, so I'm assuming boostrap.css has it as a default. I just didn't know if the specific code could be changed in my own css file, and if so what elements. It's evident in the photo there's definitely some transparent margin going on for those list elements once collapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked into a Fiddle that was created with Bootstrap in mind and threw in your code so I think I might have reproduced the issue. The problem didn't seem to be margins at all but background color that is set to `transparent` on hover/focus by default in Bootstrap.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I tested out just a simple modification to this with to override the default styles and it seemed to work.

```
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

[Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1f8b14f5/1/)

Obviously you can modify that however, but that should put you on the right track.